# Remove non printable string

Tags: c#, string, str-replace, non-printing-characters

I've done an OCR on a pdf image and extracted the text.
The OCR for some reason has converted a single space to a double carriage return line feed.

eg.

```
"\r\n\r\n"
```

The following doesn't work as I think my 4 characters are not really a stirng but 4 non printable CHARACTERS.

```
DocumentData = DocumentData.Replace(@"\r\n\r\n", "");
```

I only want to replace those 4 non printable characters with a space when they occur together.

How can this be achieved without too much fuss.

Comment: if they are non printable, remove the @ - its a verbatim string, and do what sakura wrote - " "

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the usage of the "@". By pre-pending your text with it, the escaping is ignored. Just use -

```
DocumentData = DocumentData.Replace("\r\n\r\n", " ");
```

Comment: This is wrong because you dont add `space` to string.

Comment: Modified it now to do as requested by the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
DocumentData = DocumentData.Replace("\r\n\r\n", " "); // <-- change "" to " ", remove @ char
```

Comment: He should remove the `@` in front of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure it doesn't matter what system you're (or the sender) running on and you'll always catch the non-printable I would utilize `Regular Expressions`:

```
DocumentData = Regex.Replace(DocumentData, @"\r\n?|\n|\r|\s+", " ");
```

Edit: Made the expression a touch more robust and checking for extra whitespaces replacing them with a single which will avoid excessive spacing after replacement so it's specific to this question. My Bad.

Comment: Thank you, I did end up using regex but I'm no expert in it.  My template was slightly different in that it was @"\r\n\r\n". Only replacing where all 4 non-printable characters occurred at the same time.  Won't yours also replace a single "\r\n" and single "\r" and single "\n"  occurrences ?  what does the "\s+" do ?

Comment: @user1413844 - it removes multiple whitespaces from a string. It's there because this regex method forces each character to be found and replaced with a white space, as such you get multiples. But adding `\s+` you resolve this issue as the same command will also check for multiple white spaces and replace them with a single one